# TinyMCE link browser throws connection issue

Tags: file-upload, tinymce, modx, modx-revolution

I am using TinyMCE with Modx Revo (2.1.3). When I want to add an internal file (say a PDF) via a link, I highlight the text, click the chain link icon and then the browse icon. However, instead of showing a list of existing files on my server I get a server connection error message.

I have tried this on multiple browsers and machines and get the same results.

Does anyone know if there is a file path or any permission I need to change to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

I rescently had some troubles with the tinymce file browser complaining about lack of access while the regular modx explorer worked fine. The problem was a domain plugin changing contexts on pageload, changing from "mgr" to "web".

Make sure you dont have any plugins doing something similar, and that you dont have any context settings with weird site_url settings or something like that.